# What CEF Sharp files can I safely delete?

Tags: cefsharp

I use CEFSharp solely to complete an OAUTH login sequence for a desktop app.  It is a pretty heavy tool for that job.

Looking at the files in the x86 and x64 folders that get added by CEFSharp, which ones can I safely delete?
Can I get rid of Locales?  What about SwiftShader?  What about the PDB and PAK files?

Thanks so much!

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the optional files in this link as long as your application will still be loading well.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)